# Need to customizeTextCell.TextProperty

Tags: c#, listview

i have a question hoping that someone could help me.

I have this code in one class:

```
public class Pen
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> sizes { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0}", name); }
    }
}
```

and this one on other class in order to populate a listview:

```
    public PensList()
    {
        ListView lv = new ListView();

        lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        lv.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Name");
     }
```

The listview ItemsSource as already been defined someone else on the code, and everything works like a charm, with my listview being populated with the names of every pen.

However, i need to populate other list with the sizes of each pen being the "title" of each cell in the table.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you need two different ListViews?

Comment: yes i do Artur. my second listview must present the pen's size as an individual cell at listview. lv..ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        lv.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "heresmyproblem");
     }   im simply not getting or figuring out how to put the size that i receive as strings, the same way i put the name of each pen on the previous listview